# Error in (Zip/exe) file download file download from github page relative path

Tags: github-pages

I have hosted a static website on GitHub images CSS script all work fine when linked using a relative path, however, the zip and exe file download result in an error with a 133bytes size file.

RELATIVE PATH WITH ERROR: `https://formhelper.mgeek.in/assets/release/Release.zip`
WORKING DIRECT LINK: `https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/mgeekin/formfiller.mgeek.in/main/assets/release/Release.zip`

Github says the file is stored with LFS
I also work fine on the local server.

WEBSITE:https://formhelper.mgeek.in

is there any solution or I have to manually replace RELATIVE PATH WITH ERROR to WORKING DIRECT LINK

Comment: https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/2725

Answer (score -1):

Similar problem occurs with files that are tracked by git lfs

Check status with
`git lfs track`

And to untrack run
`git lfs untrack *.zip`

As is my case it is zip you may change extension according.

After that remover file push and then add again and then push so the files stored as lfs are removed and stored as normal files.

Do comment if there is another better method to share large files.